# syntax error in the end of program

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I am trying to compile this code and it is returning a syntax error in the last line:(, have any one idea why

```
let nth_index str c n = 
let i = 0 in 
    let rec loop n i=
    let j = String.index_from str i c in
        if n>1 then loop (n-1) j 
        else    
            j
```

Comment: letting a value to i before defining loop that is using i is weird...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your outermost `let` doesn't require a matching `in`. It makes a top-level definition.

However, the other three `let`s do require a matching `in`. And you only have two `in`s.

Answer (score 2):

So, according to the @Jeffrey's response, you can write:

```
let nth_index str c n = 
    let rec loop n i =
        let j = String.index_from str i c in
        if n>1 then loop (n-1) j else j
    in loop n 0
```

But looking at your algorithm, probably you wanted to write `if n>1 then loop (n-1) (j+1) else j` in penultimate line. If yes, please note that this method can raise exception, so good practice is to name it `nth_index_exn`.